# How to set focus to datagrid placed inside a tabcontrol

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, tabcontrol, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I have a tabcontrol and I place datagrid inside a tabcontrol... But I could not focus that Datagrid at the load event ... Focus means  I couldn't navigate through keyboard into it... I'm getting this problem only inside of the tab control otherwise it works fine...

My xaml code as follows...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication12.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowState="Maximized" >
 <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top">
  <Grid>
  <TabControl x:Name="tcOpenForms" SelectedIndex="0" TabStripPlacement="Bottom" >
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="359" Name="grd_boview" Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="12" Height="640" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="BO.ID" Binding="{Binding acct_code}" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding acct_name}" Header="BO.Name" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
   </TabControl>
   </Grid>
 </Border>
</Window>
```

My C# code as follows

```
  namespace WpfApplication12
{
 /// <summary>
 /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
 /// </summary>
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
  public MainWindow()
  {
   InitializeComponent();
   Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
  }

  void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {

   SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("server=ibmserver;uid=sa;pwd=zillion;database=ecdslxyz20102011");
   SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("select * from account", sqlcon);
   SqlDataAdapter sqldac = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   sqldac.Fill(ds, "Test");
   grd_boview.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["Test"].DefaultView;
   grd_boview.Focus();
   grd_boview.SelectedIndex = 0;
  }
 }
}
```

(1)  Please note that focus means I couldn't navigate a datagrid through keyboard

(2)  It should be in load event......Because it works fine in other events...

(3)  Datagrid should be placed inside a tab control... Because it works fine outside a tab control.....

I hope u will help me...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please post your questions properly.Spend some time on that and we are happy to help